# How to handle required properties for Domain Entities?

Tags: language-agnostic, domain-driven-design, entity

I have a UserEntity that is eventually persisted in the DB according to it's `id` property. In this case, the `id` property is obviously sensitive, because changing it would cause the UserEntity to be saved over a different UserEntity when persisted later.

I would therefore like to help safe guard against something like this happening...

**Option 1. Do I FORCE the `id` to be passed into the constructor, thereby removing the Setter?**

- This would mean that every UserEntity that the Repository is given to persist will be valid (because it has the minimum requirement of an `id`).
- The downside is that my Controller wouldn't be able to create a new UserEntity() because it wouldn't have an `id` to give it.

**Option 2. Allow Id in the constructor to be null, but not provide a Setter**

- This would essentially create two types of UserEntity objects: ones that have been persisted, and ones that haven't.
- I could do new UserEntity() anywhere, fill it with it's values, then pass to the Repository who would then save it, create a new UserEntity with the new `id`, and give it back.
- This is cool, but means I need to double check that my entity has an `id` anywhere that I want to use it for persisting / domain logic / etc, to make sure that it is a saved entity.

**Option 3. Do I not worry so much, and provide a setter for it?**

- This exposes the risk of changing the `id` of a UserEntity, and overwriting a different UserEntity in the db.
- On the upside, I can create a new UserEntity() without knowing the `id` ahead of time, which I can pass to my Repository for saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you care about the validity of your domain objects, you need to ensure validity in all times.

This means that you don't provide setters on properties that you do not want changed directly, but use specified *methods* to mutate their state.

If the `id` in your example never changes, you should only ever set it in the constructor (and enforce it being passed in).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In this instance, obviously, there would most likely be no methods to mutate the `id` correct?

Comment: @johnnietheblack - From the normal context of an `id`, yes. You would provide a method for properties that do mutate but need to be validated.

Comment: @johnnietheblack, also share your doubt. Solved this problem by turning private the setter of Entities and receiving this value, and exclusively by, the constructor parameter. The method to 'add' in my Repository became responsible for returning my updated Entities with your respectives id.